# Python graphql websocket subscription client

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, graphql

I'm starting a test project where I'm required to validate graphql websocket subscription data from a python test framework.  Typically I'll just write my own libraries for interacting with the various servers, but I cannot find a reasonable description of the protocol in this case.

My question(s) is as follows:

- Is there a reasonable python library out there to function as a graphql subscription client?
- [and|or] Is there some sort of RFC, or detailed protocol description so I can just write my own?

Sorry for the basic question in advance,  My google-fu is weak this morning and while I've found several graphql python libraries, I've been struggling to find information on a reasonable client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [graphql-python/gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) package, it supports the apollo and graphql-ws protocols.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote my own client using [this document as a protocol description](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md)

And this [Python library](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-ws/tree/master/graphql_ws) to retrieve the constants